# Factorize $-x^{19}-x^{17}+x^{10}+x^8+1$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

How do I factorise the polynomial $$-x^{19}-x^{17}+x^{10}+x^8+1$$

I have been tying to solve it using vanishing method but still now unable to find any root. Any nice and helpful suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by vanishing method, can you write down your progress in your question?

Comment: For what it's worth, [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor+-x%5E%2819%29-x%5E%2817%29%2Bx%5E%2810%29%2Bx%5E8%2B1) says it is irreducible.

Comment: I have edited to make clear that the leading term has a minus sign. Is that correct? If not, it easily factorises as $(x^{10}-x^9+1)(x^9+x^8+1)$

Comment: @almagest It is...

Comment: @almagest What do you mean with "easily" ? That it is easy to find this factorization by hand ?

Comment: @Peter Yes. There are only a few things to try, such as $(x^a\pm x^b+1)(x^c+\pm x^d+1)$. We can assume that $b=8$, so $a=9$ or 10.

Comment: It is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$, it has one real root near $1^+$, and rest complex ones, and of course it will factor with real or complex coefficients, though you may need numerical methods to approximate those coefficients.  What ring are you interested in factoring this in?

Comment: @lulu: WA doesn't say so, I clicked your link. Real polynomial should be able to be factorized into quadratic and linear factor, so this should not be irreducible. It doesn't have rational roots by rational roots theorem.

Comment: @calcstudent My interpretation without any additional context would be that the factorization over $\mathbb Q[x]$ is meant because the coefficients are integers. If the factorization over $\mathbb R[x]$ is meant, this should be explicitely mentioned.

Comment: @calcstudent  I think it's clear from the context that rational factorization is what is called for here.  The unique real root can be found by numerical means, of course.  As can the various complex roots.

Comment: @Peter: the question doesn't say anything explicitly, but if it comes from school homework it's normal to let the coefficients to use n-th roots either.

Comment: @almagest Yes it's right.